# Half span in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a page using twitter bootstrap and the span and offset classes work extremely smooth. But I was wondering is there a way to span half of the normal span in twitter bootstrap without overriding the span class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Twitter Bootstrap <2.3.2 you can create fluid row in a span and inside of it 2 span6, so the 2 span6 will be always the half of the parent span.

```
<div class="span7">
    <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span6"></div>
         <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very clever, nicely done. I'm assuming this can be done down more levels so give smaller sections as well?

Comment: Exatcly. Remember that we're talking about Twitter Bootstrap versione <= 2.3.2 .

Answer (score 1):

For that you will need to use the fluid layout's. I guess making two div's of span6 inside a span3 div will give you two span1.5 div's.:

That is because **each nested level of columns should add up to 12 columns.**

```
<div class="span3">
 <div class="span6>
    ....span1.5.....
 </div>
 <div class="span6>
    ....span1.5.....
 </div>
</div>
```

Check out [**Fluid Nesting**](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think in bootstrap2, if you want for exemple a span 1.5 , you can have a span3 with a span6 inside....

```
<div class="span3">
    <span class="span6">
             m 1.5
    </span>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="span1">
    <span class="span6">
             m 0.5
    </span>
</div>
```

What do you think about it ?